# Lemniscate parametrized in polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to parametrize the lemniscate in polar coordinates.

By definition the lemniscate is the locus of all points z in complex plane, so that the product of  distances from z to $\pm 1 $ is $1$.

I found something like that: $$x^2-y^2-(x^2+y^2)^2=0$$

How can I get to that? From there it is easy to make the step  to polar coordinates.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate?

Comment: Isn't $2(x^2-y^2)-(x^2+y^2)^2=0$ ?

Comment: @Nosrati: I do not know that exactly. Therefore I  wanted to know how I get to this parameterization?

Comment: With definition $|z+1||z-1|=1$ then $|z^2-1|=1$ shows $|x^2-y^2+2ixy-1|=1$.

Comment: @Nosrati I see:) How do you solve the modulus equation?

Comment: $|u+iv|=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ then $(x^2-y^2-1)^2+(2xy)^2=1$. use $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2ac+2bc$.

Comment: @Nosrati: Thank you very much:)

Comment: You're welcome :)